# Why am I getting 'missing template arguments before f'

Tags: c++, c++11

I have simple code where I am getting to drive from `std::vector<std::string>>` but it's not working. I am getting the error:

> prog.cpp: In function `‘int main()’`:
>   prog.cpp:14:9: error: missing template arguments before `‘f’`
>       `Fun f {"a", "b", "c"};`
>            ^
>   prog.cpp:14:9: error: expected `‘;’` before `‘f’`

Here is the code. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <vector>
>
> template<
>     class String = std::string,
>     class List   = std::vector<String>
> > class Fun : public List
> { };
>
> int main()
> {
>     Fun f {"a", "b", "c"};
>  }
> ```

Comment: What compiler and environment are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TimoGeusch I'm compiling on Ideone (GCC 4.8.1)

Comment: I think you haven't fetched template types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use

```
int main()
{
  Fun<> f {"a", "b", "c"};
}
```

Because Fun is a template.

It's like if you called "function" instead of "function()" by the fact of not having parameters.

You could say that "you are instantiating a template class so it returns a class".

Answer (score 3):

Even though you've specified defaults for the template parameters, you need to include an empty parameter list to instantiate the template:

```
Fun<> f{"a", "b", "c"};
```

Of course, for that to work you'll still need a ctor for `Fun` that accepts the three strings you're passing.

Finally (also an "of course") the standard container classes (including `vector<std::string>`) are not intended to be used as base classes, so this really isn't a good idea in general.

Answer (score 2):

Fun is still a template, so you have to write code this way:

```
Fun<> f {"a", "b", "c"};
```

You also have to provide an appropriate constructor.